# C# Encoding from utf-16 to ascii

Tags: c#

I get question marks in output of my program: ?????? ??????

```
 string str = "Привет медвед";
        Encoding srcEncodingFormat = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-16");
        Encoding dstEncodingFormat = Encoding.ASCII;
        byte [] originalByteString = srcEncodingFormat.GetBytes(str);
        byte [] convertedByteString =  Encoding.Convert(srcEncodingFormat,
                                                       dstEncodingFormat, originalByteString);
        string finalString = dstEncodingFormat.GetString(convertedByteString);
        Console.WriteLine (finalString);
```

Comment: ASCII does not have those characters. [Read up on encoding](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: Pretty sure it's because the Console can't display Cyrillic rather than a problem with your method.

Comment: Crowcoder, thank for your link, but my english is very bad :( why my input string doesn't change if i write: 
string str = "Привет";
   Encoding srcEncodingFormat = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-16");
   Encoding dstEncodingFormat = Encoding.GetEncoding("koi8-r");
How i can see result of encoding.convert cyrrilic letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no text but encoded text. But, .NET's char and string use Unicode/UTF-16, as you know. So, you can simplify your code by calling GetBytes and passing in the string instead of doing it twice as your code does.

As for your question, you have a choice of a lossy conversion or no conversion at all. Below is code that prevents a lossy conversion.

Now, how to see the result? As with all text, it is a sequence of bytes. Your best bet is to write them to a file and open the file in an editor that you can indicate the encoding to and that can use a font that supports the characters you want to see.

```
string str = "Привет медвед";
Encoding dstEncodingFormat = Encoding.GetEncoding("US-ASCII", 
    new EncoderExceptionFallback(), 
    new DecoderReplacementFallback());
byte[] output = dstEncodingFormat.GetBytes(str);
File.WriteAllBytes("Test Привет медвед.txt", output);
```

Comment: You can just use `Encoding.ASCII`; no need to look it up from string.

Comment: @Nyerguds The point is to get an encoding that throws an exception when expectations are not met (bug) rather the ones that corrupt the user's text by removing data on the theory that some is better than none. I don't fully subscribe to that theory. Those encodings do insert marker characters � or ? to indicate the data loss to the users but the programmers never find out that they've messed up. (Yes, there are some cases where the requirement is to remove data but in most such cases a transliteration would be preferred to data loss.)

Comment: @Nyerguds Some of the constructors have equivalent parameters but ASCIIEncoding does not. Example: [`new UTF8Encoding(_, true)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.utf8encoding.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Text_UTF8Encoding__ctor_System_Boolean_System_Boolean_) IMO, `throwOnInvalidBytes` should be the default.